# Is it possible to get a default token which doesn't overrides the already present tokens in ANTLR3?

Tags: c#, antlr3

I have a requirement wherein I have written the Lexer token as:

```
IF_LEXER_TOKEN: 'IF' (.)* 'END_IF'
ANY :(options {greedy=true;}: .)* ;
```

But if the input is given as:

```
IF a>b then a=b END_IF
IF c>d then c=d
```

In this case the expected behavior is that it should use the token `IF_LEXER_TOKEN` for first line and ANY token for second line, but instead its considering the ANY token for both lines. Kindly help. Note:Due to some constraints I can't create a parser rule for the above scenario.

Comment: FYI, `('E')('N')('D')('_')('I')('F')` and `'END_IF'` are equivalent.

Comment: Yes I know that but the problem is with respect to the token being called in the above input

Comment: That is why I added a comment, not an answer. If you know they're equivalent, why write it as `('E')('N')('D')('_')('I')('F')` to begin with? Writing it like that has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: Why use ANTLR3 instead of ANTLR4?

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be: don't do what you're trying to do. Never use `.*` or `.+` at the end of a lexer rule: it consumes everything until `EOF`.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems to me you're trying to get an answer to problem `Y`<sup>1</sup>, while you ought to be explaining problem `X`<sup>1</sup>.

> <sup>1</sup> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem